# MATLAB Multi-resolution technique for a large mesh

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, resolution, mesh, deepzoom

I was hoping if someone could help me point to the right direction when it comes to visualizing large 3D point clouds without downsampling in MATLAB. The large 3-D points clouds will ultimately be converted to mesh for visualization. Now I have looked up functions like scatter3 and fscatter3. However they deal with downsampling data. I want to preserve all the points in my data. I have over 100 million points. I understand that there is no possible way to show that many pixels on a desktop screen. However I was wondering if there was a technique to focus into the data as you zoom into it (like the tile zoom in Google Maps). For instance the mesh will have higher resolution as you zoom in further into the mesh. I looked up and found that "plot (Big)" was available for 2D data. I am wondering if there is a similar library for a 3D mesh? Apologies if this question sounds trivial.

Comment: I doubt whether this amount of data can be visualized efficiently using MATLAB. You could consider [MATLAB to Point Cloud Library](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40382-matlab-to-point-cloud-library).

Comment: I have been using those commands in MATLAB to PCL library. Those commands helped me read and write point clouds, however I could not find a library for efficiently representing large point clouds in a multi-resolution format.

Comment: Do you need the possibility to rotate the visualization? Is it a scatter (different sized points) or just a cloud of points. Maybe the visualization could be rendered offline to 2d images.

Comment: Yes, rotation would be needed for the visualization. It is just a cloud of points. My goal is to convert that point cloud into a mesh using the MATLAB function surf or mesh and having a multi-resolution for that mesh. The problem is that I cannot find a way to process and visualize the mesh in a multi-resolution format. I am editing the question to include the fact that it is a mesh